# Always crashes when choosing symbology "unique values"

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.4, serious-application-error

Using ArcGIS 10.4

I have a polygon shapefile with many columns, one is called "coding". It includes pure numbers like 31001

Now I need this as a raster with this code as the value. So I tried, as usual, the "feature to raster" tool. It worked fine. It shows me the values as stretched though. Whenever I try to change the symbology to "Unique values" ArcMap crashes immediately. Also I cant reclassify it, because it wont show me unique values. But that is exactly what I need to do, because I need to group certain codes into one. 
Any ideas what to do? Is there something wrong with the raster?

Comment: By "crashes" do you mean that you get a Serious Application Error or something else?

Comment: Normally it should works, maybe because the raster is huge. just try to restart windows, restart ArcMap, add the new raster in a new blank map and try to change the symbology.

Comment: I mean that ArcMap shuts down completely and asks me to send a error message to Esri. Unfortunately restarting everything didnt help. What confuses me is that its also not possible to click "unique" in the reclassify window. Maybe ArcMap doesnt understand that the codes are not rising numbers but a little random like 31001 43020202 etc. But that should be no issue!?

Comment: Nice you managed and found the mistake. I think with many unique values it can happen that the size gets too big and ArcGIS crashes due to that as well...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally managed!
For some reason the new raster had the wrong format (pixel type). Copying the raster and changing the pixel type did the trick.
Thank you anyway.